# With turbolinks, jQuery stops working until a hard refresh

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, turbolinks

I implemented a dynamic select menu thanks to the related RailsCast video. It worked well but now I have to refresh my webpage so that my JQuery code, written in my .coffee script can work.

I read on the internet that people using javascript and who wrote `$(document).ready(function())` had to change this part of the code in `$(document).bind('pageinit')`.

The problem is that I don't know how to adapt this to my `.coffee` file.

I read also about using **PJAX** but Turbolinks is supposed to do the same job only this kind of problem may happen with Turbolinks.

My **Turbolink gem** is in my GemFile and it is **required** in my `application.js` file.

**What shall I write so that I do not have to refresh my webpage in order to have the JQuery code to work directly ?**

Here is the code in my `.coffee` file :

```
jQuery ->
  $('#test_contrat_id').parent().hide()
  contrats = $('#test_contrat_id').html()

  $('#test_employe_id').change ->
    employe = $('#test_employe_id :selected').text()
    escaped_employe = employe.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
    options = $(contrats).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_employe}']").html()
    if options
      $('#test_contrat_id').html(options)
      $('#test_contrat_id').parent().show()
    else
      $('#test_contrat_id').empty()
      $('#test_contrat_id').parent().hide()
```

And here is the code written in my form :

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :employe_id %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select :employe_id, Employe.order(:nom_employe), :id, :nom_employe, include_blank: true %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :contrat_id %><br>
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :contrat_id, Employe.order(:nom_employe), :contrats, :nom_employe, :id, :nom_contrat, include_blank: true%>
</div>
```

Comment: I found the problem. I disabled the gem turbolink and I used a double trigger in my javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *do not have* to use `jquery.turbolinks` like the other answer states. You just need to wait to run your javascript until Turbolinks triggers the page:load event.

**See bottom of post for update for Turbolinks 5**

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  # granted I don't know the context here, but instead of using javascript to hide something on DOM load, I would use CSS. Look below for that solution.
  $('#test_contrat_id').parent().hide()


$(document).on 'change', '#test_employe_id', (e) ->
  contrats = $('#test_contrat_id').html()
  employe = $('#test_employe_id :selected').text()
  escaped_employe = employe.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
  options = $(contrats).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_employe}']").html()
  if options
    $('#test_contrat_id').html(options)
    $('#test_contrat_id').parent().show()
  else
    $('#test_contrat_id').empty()
    $('#test_contrat_id').parentemploye
```

---

For above CSS comment...

```
# css file
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden !important;
}

# add the class .hidden to that element in your view.

# your CoffeeScript will now be
$(document).on 'change', '#test_employe_id', (e) ->
  contrats = $('#test_contrat_id').html()
  employe = $('#test_employe_id :selected').text()
  escaped_employe = employe.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
  options = $(contrats).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_employe}']").html()
  if options
    $('#test_contrat_id').html(options)
    $('#test_contrat_id').parent().removeClass('hidden')
  else
    $('#test_contrat_id').empty()
    $('#test_contrat_id').parent().addClass('hidden')
```

[This GitHub thread](https://github.com/jquery/jquery.com/issues/88) is very interesting and worth your read about using `.hide()` and `.show()`.

---

**Turbolinks 5**

Turbolinks 5 adds their own event listeners, so you no longer need to use `ready page:load`.

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried and my field contrat is now hidden as expected (indeed I have to choose an employe so that the field appears) but when I choose an employe the contrat field does not appear. The behaviour of my code looks now to be random. I clicked on one of the employee and the contrat field appears.  However all employe in my database have several contrat so contrat is not an empty list. To sum up sometimes your solution works but the majority of the time it does not.

Comment: What code are you using to make it re-appear? also, if your change event, in your `else` statement, what is `$('#test_contrat_id').parentemploye` supposed to be? copy/paste error?

Comment: Yes it's copy/paste mistake the code is not `.parentemploye` but `.parent().hide()`I am going to edit my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "What code are you using to make it re-appear?"...you mean in the initial code what is supposed to hide or not the field contrat ?

Comment: So change it to .parent().addClass('hidden')

Comment: it is the same. I noticed that it is always the third try to select an employe that succeeds. Whatever employe it is. So when I load the page the first time I choose an employe but the contrat related to that employe do not appear but the third try succeeds and then again it fails. Weird.

Comment: @GDMN the important thing to note, is that for turbolinks, you need `$(document).on('page:change', ())`, not bind. That can be found in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#page-change-events). The answer above has adopted it into coffeescript, but just wanted to share this extra information

Comment: I eventually found a solution. I used a `on:('page:load')` thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Turbolink was the problem. I first used a double trigger and it work well.

I wrote instead of :

```
$(document).ready(function(){my code});
```

something like this :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var ready = function(){
        //all my javascript code
      };

      $(document).ready(ready);
      $(document).on('page:load',ready);

    </script>
```

But then I still had some problems. So I uninstalled the gem `turbolink`in my GemFile and now everything works well.

It looks like problems about hard refresh are related to Turbolink.

Comment: This is a bad answer and should not be the selected answer. Turbolinks is just misunderstood, but when used properly, it's a huge asset to your application. My answer above tells you how to use Turbolinks properly, with the `on 'ready page:load'` event, instead of `ready`.

Comment: This is a great answer. No one is should have to rewrite all of their Javascript, and then all third-party Javascript, for this questionable optimization. Removing Turbolinks makes Javascript events work as documented. It's important for code to work as documented, especially in a browser environment. Getting Javascript to work properly across all browsers, every time, is tricky enough. No need to do it on hard mode.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gems for run JavaScript as well as

Comment: No you don't. You just need to trigger the page:load event.

Comment: actually jquery turbolinks did this instead of write page load, you just write documet ready and use jquery turbolinks, its run your script with turbolinks, just use once and then tell me i m right or wrong

Comment: I was just saying you don't _need_ to use it. There is no need to add an extra dependency to your project if you can just bind your DOM load to the correct events.